# Incompatible type on assignment, from BSTNode* to BSTNode*

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a binary search tree. I am working on the insert function, but i am getting several incompatible types warnings.

```
warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'BSTNode *' to 'BSTNode *'
```

I am getting these warnings on lines 22, 25, 36, and 36 of my code. I am also getting the warning `warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'BSTNode *' to 'BSTNode *'` on my two recursive calls. I marked the errors in the code below with comments. These are the same type, so I cannot figure out what is causing these warnings.

```
//BST.c

#include "BST.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void insert(BSTNode* top_of_bst,BSTNode* node){


   //no items in bst, add it to the top
   if (top_of_bst == NULL){
      top_of_bst->node_value = node->node_value;
      top_of_bst->left = NULL;
      top_of_bst->right = NULL;
      top_of_bst->parent = NULL;
      return;
   }

  //if the value is smaller check the left child
  if (top_of_bst->node_value >= node->node_value){
      if (top_of_bst->left == NULL){
         node->parent = top_of_bst;  //HERE IS AN ERROR
         node->right = NULL;
         node->left = NULL;
         top_of_bst->left = node;   //HERE IS AN ERROR
         return;
      }
      //if the left child exists, recurse left
      else
         insert(top_of_bst->left, node);  //HERE IS AN ERROR
   }
   //if the value is bigger check the right child
    else{
       if (top_of_bst->right == NULL){
          top_of_bst->right = node; //HERE IS AN ERROR
          node->parent = top_of_bst;   //HERE IS AN ERROR
          node->left = NULL;
          node->right = NULL;
          return;
       }
       //if the child exists, recurse right
       else
          insert(top_of_bst->right, node);   //HERE IS AN ERROR
    }
}
```

And this is my BstNode header file

```
#ifndef BSTNODE_H
#define BSTNODE_H

typedef struct BSTNODE{
   struct BSTNode* parent;
   struct BSTNode* left;
   struct BSTNode* right;
   int node_value;
}BSTNode;

#endif
```

Comment: Use `struct BSTNODE*` instead of `struct BSTNode*`.  The typedef'ed name isn't usable yet inside the struct definition, and if it were you wouldn't need `struct` in front of it anyway.

Comment: Which lines EXACTLY? You did not show any line numbers. Also, when `top_of_bst` is NULL, your code is going to crash accessing its members, since you are not creating a new `BSTNode` first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your header file

```
struct BSTNode* parent;
struct BSTNode* left;
struct BSTNode* right;
```

should be

```
struct BSTNODE* parent;
struct BSTNODE* left;
struct BSTNODE* right;
```

because, while defining the members, `BSTNode` is not known.

Otherwise, you can also have the `typedef struct BSTNODE BSTNode;` before the structure definition and use like

```
BSTNode* parent;
BSTNode* left;
BSTNode* right;
```

Comment: This was a fast one

Answer (score 3):

struct should be like below. You cannot reference typedef alias before the definition is complete.

```
typedef struct BSTNODE{
   struct BSTNODE* parent;
   struct BSTNODE* left;
   struct BSTNODE* right;
   int node_value;
}BSTNode;
```